# Add WebClient to form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, webclient

In Visual Studio 2017, you can add components to a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` like `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`:
[image: Components] [image: Toolbox]
My question is: Can you also do this for `System.Net.WebClient`? I know I can add a public instance to the top of my class:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form {
    WebClient wc;

    public FrmMain() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

but I would like it to be defined by Visual Studio, in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is derived from `Component`. It means it's ready to show in toolbox of a Windows Forms project without additional effort.

To do so, it's enough to right click on toolbox and select *Choose Items ...* then, in list of *.Net Framework Components* finds *WebClient* and check the checkmark near it and add it to toolbox.

Then you can drop an instance of the component on your form and use it.